# Does mmap share memory with all processes?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, shared-memory, mmap

When I do this :

```
myProgram.h
myProgram.c

    struct PipeShm
    {
    // all my fields
    // more 
    // ...

    };



    struct PipeShm myPipe = { /* initialization for all fields */ };
    struct PipeShm * sharedPipe = &myPipe;

void func()
{
 sharedPipe = mmap (NULL, sizeof * sharedPipe, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

}
```

When I `mmap` the pointer `sharedPipe`, if I invoke from `main()` any methods from `myProgram` code, would all processes share the exact shared memory that I shared with `myPipe` struct?

Or would each new child that's created, would have a new `myPipe` of his own?

Regards

**EDIT:**

This is after I read the comments & answers : now changes were made , and I initialize the values of the segment only after I allocate it :

```
#include "my_pipe.h"

struct PipeShm * sharedPipe = NULL;



int shm_pipe_init()
{
    if (!sharedPipe)
    {
        int myFd = shm_open ("/myregion", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 0600);

        if (myFd == -1)
            error_out ("shm_open");

        // Allocate some memory in the region - We use ftruncate, write(2) would work just as well
        int retAlloc = ftruncate (myFd, sizeof * sharedPipe);
        if (retAlloc < 0)
            error_out("ftruncate");


        sharedPipe = mmap (NULL, sizeof * sharedPipe,
                PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, myFd, 0);

        if (!sem_init (&sharedPipe->semaphore, 1, 0))
        {
            sharedPipe->init = TRUE;
            sharedPipe->flag = FALSE;
            sharedPipe->ptr1 = NULL;
            sharedPipe->ptr2 = NULL;
            sharedPipe->status1 = -10;
            sharedPipe->status2 = -10;
            sharedPipe->semaphoreFlag = FALSE;
            sharedPipe->currentPipeIndex = 0;

        }
        else
            perror ("shm_pipe_init");
    }
    return 1;   // always successful
}
```

The problem however continues ,the shared memory seems to be not so shared between the processes , since while running and forking that main :

```
int main()
{
    int spd, pid, rb;
    char buff[4096];

    fork();
    shm_pipe_init();

        // more
        return 0;
}
```

I still get outputs , that simulates the behavior like only one process is running (instead of multiple outputs , I get only a single **one** or a **couple** ,depends on a race condition between the processes) .

Comment: what do you mean by "all processes"? All processes in the system, or all child processes of the original, etc?

Comment: @tbert: All the processes - meaning child processes , grandsons ...etc

Comment: Writing hint: There is no blank before punctuation (comma, colon, semicolon, full stop, question mark etc.) in English.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you intend to call this program several times, the answer is "no". If you intend to fork after creating the mapping, the answer is "yes".

An anonymous mapping has no underlying file. Therefore, a process creating an anonymous mapping has no way of specifying which already existing mapping in particular it wants (and this is also not the intended usage, you're supposed to get a new, independent one). Therefore "no" to the first case.

A shared mapping allows all processes that own the same mapping to access the same phsyical memory. This means, if you `fork` after creating the mapping, then `fork` will mostly work the usual way, marking all pages owned by the process as copy-on-write **except** the pages in the mapping. Both the parent and the child will retain the mapped pages and will be able to access the same physical memory through the pointer (incidentially, this means the pages will even have the same *virtual* addresses, too -- this is normally not something you can rely on when mapping a file, but in this case the OS has no other choice but to make sure this is the case).

The manpages remain vague about the combination of anonymous and shared mapping or about what exactly is supposed to happen, but TLPI chapter 49.7 explicitly mentions `MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS`:

> [...] followed by a call to fork(), then, because the child produced by fork() inherits the mapping, both processes share the memory region.

Therefore "yes" for the second case.

**Re: edited post**
Wrong order:

```
fork();
shm_pipe_init();
```

This forks **first** and then initializes the shared memory. Which will just create a shared (read as share-*able*, it may be shared in the future, if the process forks again, but it does not magically back-share with the parent!) mapping *for each process*, separately.

You then have **two** mappings, one in each process, which will be shared by their respective child and grandchild processes (if any), but which will help nothing to achieve what you want. The fact that they are "shared" does not matter, they're different mappings, and unknown to the respective other process.

**First** create the mapping, **then** fork. This will create *one* shared mapping that both processes indeed own/share and can use for the intended purpose.

(Besides, your usage of `fork` is not strictly wrong, but a bit weird... you're normally supposed to check the return value, so you know which one is the parent and which one is the child. And it's not like `fork` can't fail. Of course if that doesn't matter at all because parent and child are always 100% identical and you don't care about failure, that's fine. Normally, one usually wants to know, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Let's step through what you're exactly doing here

```
struct PipeShm myPipe = { /* initialization for all fields */ };
```

This allocates a `PipeShm` structure as a global variable

```
struct PipeShm * sharedPipe = &myPipe;
```

This creates a pointer to previously created structure.

Now you're modifying the pointer `sharedPipe` to what `mmap` returns (presumably an address to a region of shared memory) instead of the structure you allocated before (note: `myPipe` still exists - just not pointed to).

```
sharedPipe = mmap (NULL, sizeof * sharedPipe, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

As far as I can see, you've also made no attempts to access `sharedPipe`. So now, you basically have a global variable *and* a section of shared memory (both of which appear unused).

This is where I'm not so sure what you're trying to do.

If you want to access the shared memory, you'll need to dereference the `sharedPipe` pointer after `mmap` returns (if so, what was the point of the global variable?).

If you want to access the global variable, just access it as `myPipe` (if so, what was `mmap` for?).

If you want to access both, then use a combination of the above (if so, what was the point of doing `struct PipeShm * sharedPipe = &myPipe;`?)

Comment: Please see the modified post , I did as you said ... you were right!

Answer (score 2):

Each would have its own, since changes to the **pointer** `sharedPipe` do *not* affect `myPipe`.

Comment: OK , then how can I change the above to make all processes (child-processes) to have the same memory ? thanks

Comment: They already do. **In `sharedPipe`.** You must dereference it to access the fields.

Comment: You mean that : `struct PipeShm * sharedPipe = myPipe;` ? if so , this is does not compile .

Comment: @ron, I would suggest you should do ..shm_open(to get a shared memory), ftruncate (set the set of the size of the memory to your structure's size) and then mmap (get the pointer, then initialise it by accessing the members of the structure). This mapped memory (that is the pointer) should be available to use for all the processes that you are referring.

Comment: @Tanmoy: Please see the modified post , I did what you suggested , however the problem still stands.

Comment: @ron, seems I am seeing your comment a liitle late. Is this solved?I can see you are forking and then initialising the shared memory? Are you sure to initialise it twice? I might be missing something, while following your post. In any case if the code is still not working as intended, can you pl. paste it in pastebin so that I can have a look. Also pl. mention the expected behaviour.